# How to dynamically zoom google map based on the markers count?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have initially setup a zoom level for google map, I would like to change the zoom level dynamically based on the number of markers present in the bounds. In case there are no markers present in the initial map zoom, I am not able to change the zoom dynamically by changing the map bounds.

In case there are no markers in the bounds, I am adding new markers in the bound and animating the camera to incorporate new bounds but what actually it is doing is changing the centre of the map to a new place instead of my current location. I don't want to change my current place, I just want to zoom out the map to include those markers.

```
if(noMarkersInBound){
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(new LatLng(28.5795431, 77.317322));
    builder.include(new LatLng(28.5805431, 77.328322));
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,0);
}
```

This method `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds` is changing the current place to that bound instead of zooming out the map.

Can anyone help or tell me an approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but if all you want to do is set the zoom level then just do that:

> public static CameraUpdate zoomTo (float zoom) Returns a CameraUpdate
>   that moves the camera viewpoint to a particular zoom level.
>
> Parameters zoom   the desired zoom level, in the range of 2.0 to 21.0.
>   Values below this range are set to 2.0, and values above it are set to
>   21.0. Increase the value to zoom in. Not all areas have tiles at the largest zoom levels.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#zoomTo(float)

> public void moveCamera (CameraUpdate update) Repositions the camera
>   according to the instructions defined in the update. The move is
>   instantaneous, and a subsequent getCameraPosition() will reflect the
>   new position. See CameraUpdateFactory for a set of updates.
>
> Parameters update The change that should be applied to the camera.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)

Comment: I want the zoom level to calculate based on the number of markers. How do I calculate it dynamically? If there are no markers in the bounds, map should zoom out to a particular value.

Comment: You want to set the zoom level based on the number of markers, or set it so all the markers are displayed?  And my answer shows how to zoom to a particular level.